# What's the reason of using the function head() in rmanovab (WRS2 R package)?

Tags: r

I would like to know why do I need to use the head(data) function in rmanovab (WRS2 R package)? For example:

head(WineTasting)
    rmanova(WineTasting$Taste, WineTasting$Wine, WineTasting$Taster)

(Source: WRS2 user manual)

If my data contains hundreds or thousands of rows, do I need to use head(data) before rmanovab?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to use `head()`. That's just to take a quick look at the data before analyzing it. `head()` just prints the first few rows.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just a choice the author of the package make when writing the manual. It is a common practice to inspect data before performing operations on it. `head()` will give you the top rows of a given input. You can test this by running the example provided in the manual:

```
> head(WineTasting)
   Taste   Wine Taster
 1  5.40 Wine A      1
 2  5.50 Wine B      1
.....
> rmanova(WineTasting$Taste, WineTasting$Wine, WineTasting$Taster)
  Test statistic: F = 3.2614
  .....
```

Note the `....`  were added by me to keep this post breif. Here is the same code without head.

```
> rmanova(WineTasting$Taste, WineTasting$Wine, WineTasting$Taster)
  Test statistic: F = 3.2614
  .....
```

The F statistic has not changed. `head()` does not matter for running the packages- but it does matter if you want to know what the data frame for the manual's example contains.